# how to add delay before returning a value in javascript function

Tags: javascript, timeout, delay

I need to add a 2 seconds delay before returning a value in Javascript function

```
function slowFunction(num) {
  console.log("Calling slow function");
 
  // 2 seconds delay here

  return num * 2;
}
```

Comment: What is your use case that requires this delay? And what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways to do this.

I prefer using promises.

```
function sleep(delay: number): Promise<void>{
   return new Promise( (res) => {
        setTimeout(()=>res(),delay)
   })
}

async function slowFunction(num) {
  console.log("Calling slow function");
  await sleep(2000)
  // 2 seconds delay here

  return num * 2;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Why the slowFunction also returning a promise

Comment: thats because I add async on function. You should check up on how promises work, and how async await works.